# npm install jsdom error on windows?

Tags: node.js, npm, jsdom

I have installed nodejs on my windows pc. And it was working fine. But when I tried to install jsdom using 
"npm install jsdom" I was prompoted by this error.

> node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild                                                    info it
>   worked if it ends with ok
>   ERR! Error: Python does not seem to be installed
>   at failNoPython (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:78:14)
>   at Object.oncomplete (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:66:11)
>   ERR! not ok
>   npm WARN optional dependency failed, continuing contextify@0.1.2
>   jsdom@0.2.13 ./node_modules/jsdom
>   +-- cssom@0.2.3                                                                 +-- htmlparser@1.7.5

Can anyone help me regarding this problem?

Comment: Error: Python does not seem to be installed, seems you have to install python

Comment: Yes, but after i received the error i downloaded and installed pythong from python.org, however the error still shows up.. thanks

Comment: @stewe Does it need to be a specific version of Python? Should it be Python 2, or Python 3? I'm still trying to figure this out.

Comment: If you don't need the full feature-set of jsdom/Contextify, **[Cheerio](http://matthewmueller.github.com/cheerio/)** is: * Much faster
* Much easier to install
* More resilient to broken HTML (compared with jsdom)
* And provides most of the jQuery functions you would use server-side http://matthewmueller.github.com/cheerio/

Comment: You have to install Python 2.x instead of 3.x

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue on Windows 7 (x64 Ultimate), after hours of search and trials, here is how I resolved it. Please follow the steps in the same exact order:

1. Install Visual Studio 2010/2012 C++ (Express or higher)
2. Install Windows SDK 7.1
3. Install "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1"
4. Install GTK (C:\GTK)
5. Install Python (C:\Python27)
6. Install node.js (x86)
7. Add [node.js] to path (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;)
8. Add [python] to path (C:\Python27\;)
9. Add [GTK] to path (C:\GTK\bin;)
10. Add [WindowsSDKDir] System Variable pointing to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin"
11. Run "Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt" as Administrator
12. Set environment to x86 using "setenv /x86"
13. Change directory to "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"
14. Run "npm install -g npm"
15. Run "npm update -g npm"
16. Run "npm install -g node-gyp"
17. Run "node-gyp configure build"
18. Run "npm install jsdom"
19. Run "npm install ajax"
20. Run "npm install http-server"
21. Run "npm install jquery"
22. Run "npm install xmlhttprequest"
23. Run "npm update"

I hope this helps.

Comment: Works for me though I did not install GTK. Thanks very much for this great answer

Comment: This worked for me too. No GTK here either. A couple snags for me though. In order to install Windows SDK 7.1 I had to make sure to uninstall all Visual Studio 2010 Redistributables. Also, I had to run `node-gyp rebuild --msvs_version=2012`. Thanks!

Comment: I had to add C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin to PATH so setenv works

Comment: Thanks great findings.. too many dependencies for just NodeJS... how about on Mac could it be simpler ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice guide to getting JSDom working on Windows here: http://www.steveworkman.com/node-js/2012/installing-jsdom-on-windows/

Comment: Unfortunately the linked article no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

jsdom has a dependency on contextify, which only recently supports windows. You'll need python and a C++ compiler to install it.

You may also need to do the following

```
npm install -g node-gyp
node-gyp configure
```

Comment: I have cygwin and Mingw installed with c++ compilers, I have also install python from python.org after I have received this error but the error still remains.

Answer (score 1):

For windows 8 64-bit, installing zmq and protobuf, the following worked for me:

First, Install [Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=34673)

Then, on the command prompt (in your project directory):

```
SET VisualStudioVersion=11.0
npm install zmq
npm install protobuf
npm install jsdom
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I suspect that not everyone will have Visual Studio 2012 installed.

Answer (score 1):

`jsdom` uses `contextify` for running JavaScript on the DOM. And `contextify` requires native C++ compiler. According to [the official readme](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#contextify), on Windows platform, one has to install:

1. A recent copy of the x86 version of Node.js for Windows, not the x64 version. (should be okay by default)
2. A copy of Visual C++ 2010 Express. (or any newer version)
3. A copy of Python 2.7, installed in the default location of `C:\Python27`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have python installed already, you would need to add the python install directory to the *PATH* environment variable.

Assuming that *python.exe* is in the `C:\Python32\` directory, on the DOS prompt you need to type:

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python32\;`

and then:

`node-gyp configure`

should work fine without *that* error.

Answer (score 0):

After almost a half year of solving this issue, reading all forums related to this, I finally found the solution.

What I did was simple in my case because I don't use many apps on this computer.

My Windows 8.1 had many programs installed which confused the NodeJS probably (Frameworks, VS addons, etc.).

So I simply did this:

- Removed all programs from MS, that I installed once.
- Uninstalled **Nodejs**
- For sure I cleaned the registry with [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download)
- Removed Python, Node-gyp and other apps related to Node.js

Then I reinstalled Node.js with optimism for JSdom which installed correctly, but crashed while running my project. So I searched for the new error which -  again - has a simple solution. **I had to install an older version of JSdom.**

```
npm install jsdom@4.2.0
```

Finally, everything works. Hope that helps anyone with this issue.