# Not able to install npm package PM2 in windows 7

Tags: node.js, npm

Not able to install npm package PM2 in windows 7 we are getting below error

```
> usage@0.3.9 install C:\Users\evaith\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\usage
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\evaith\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\usage>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\b
in\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:118:
14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:81:11
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuil
d"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\evaith\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\usage
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.21
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm ERR! not ok code 0
PS C:\Users\evaith>
```

Why it looking for Python path.

Comment: I think, you need to install python first.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970329/npm-install-jsdom-error-on-windows)

Comment: Be aware of pm2 in windows. Right now is only intended to work in Linux and MacOS. Check the project in github or [this issue](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/6)

Comment: You are better off developing on linux. A lot of npm modules which have non JS code (c++ mostly) aren't built to work on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PM2 uses native components which require compilation. Many node packages utilize node-gyp ([reference](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp)) to make building native C/C++ code cross platform more convenient and reliable.

One of the dependencies of `node-gyp` is the 2.7.3+ series of Python (3.x is not compatible). So, in order to compile a package that does not already include native binaries or a fall back to JavaScript, you may need Python. But, if you are compiling on Windows, you'll also need to have a compiler. I'd suggest following the instructions on the `node-gyp` web page (you'll need to install a free version of Visual Studio).

But, you'll encounter the more serious error later that PM2 isn't supported on Windows ( 
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/6?source=cc).

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.

Install `python`? [Get it here](http://www.python.org/getit/windows/)

Comment: Why PM2 looking for python?

Comment: `node-gyp`, presumably one of its dependencies needs to compile something with it.